# What is "dirty" memory in Instruments?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, instruments, allocation

When I monitor my application using instruments and the instrument "allocations" I see a big amount of memory being marked as "dirty". What does that mean? I have no memory leaks in my application yet this pile of "dirty" memory keeps increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirty is a computer term used to denote cached data that needs to be sync'ed  with the main memory. Don't worry, since this is automatically done by the hardware.

Comment: hm yeah the thing is that my application keeps using more and more ( steadily ) while there are no real leaks in the application. Thats why  I am trying to find out what is using up all my memory.

Answer (score 2):

"...I am trying to find out what is using up all my memory."

The WWDC 2010 Session 311 presentation, *Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments*, includes a section on 'Responding to Memory Warnings' (at  ~38:40 in the video) with a demo that illustrates how to find "resident, dirty memory" with the Instruments VM Tracker and one way to flush it.