# iOS memory leak on app loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I'm trying to find a memory leak i have on my app. When the application loads i instantly get a memory leak that looks like that in instuments

[image: leak]

[image: cycles and roots]

how can i debug that ? it doesn't reproduce it self no matter how long i run my app or what i do, only when the applications loads.

and here is my code in the delegate

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{   

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    search = [[iPhoneView alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhoneView" bundle:nil];
    homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:search];

    favouritesNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    favoritesViewController = [[FavoritesViewController alloc]init];
    [favouritesNavigationController pushViewController:favoritesViewController animated:NO];

    aboutUsViewController =[[AboutUsViewController alloc] init];

    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"toolbox" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aboutus"] tag:0];
    aboutUsViewController.tabBarItem = item;
    [item release];

    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"αγαπημένα" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites"] tag:0];
    favouritesNavigationController.tabBarItem = item2;
    [item2 release];

    NSArray *tabBarControllerCollection = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavigationController,favouritesNavigationController,aboutUsViewController,nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:tabBarControllerCollection animated:NO];

    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [tabBarControllerCollection release];   //added that for the leaks

    //[window addSubview:tabBarController.view]; for the warning thing about window and root view controller
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [tabBarController release];
    [search release];
    [favoritesViewController release];
    [favouritesNavigationController release];
    [aboutUsViewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: It could be anywhere in the init code of the view controllers you create there too, that's potentially quite a bit of code to check :) Maybe somebody has a good idea to systematically home in on the problem, I'd be interested in that as well

Comment: did you use ARC? the "- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
" Method is deprecated please use: "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:"(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: no i'm not using ARC ok i'll change that too didn't get any warning about that so!

Comment: Yes i know it could be anywhere, but the leak appears really soon and always at the same time so i thought it should be on the delegate or sth.

Comment: Are you profiling the app in the simulator or on the device? What is your deployment target? 5.0? 5.1?

Answer (score 2):

Please use the Call Tree view of your Leaks, that will show where the problem happened and will help you troubleshoot. Also try with a real device as the simulator might show false-positives.

[image: Leaks call tree]

Comment: if using the call tree i don't get anything it's empty thats why i can't debug!

Comment: i added one more screenshot from cycles

Comment: Sorry that was not clear. Do you have any filters set for the leaks display (panel below the Leaks)?

Comment: And do you use the simulator or a real device? Is it the same for both?

Comment: no i don't have any filter enabled. also it's tested on simulator 5.1 and on device, happens every time on loading not even the splash screen disappears and the leak is there!

Comment: Do you see only leaks or global memory usage is increasing? Look at dirty memory, also look at videos from Apple WWDC 2012 regarding memory leak troubleshooting - might help.

Comment: no i see only leaks the memory doesn't increase. What is the dirty memory?

Comment: Dirty memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443606/what-isdirty-memory-in-instruments

Answer (score 1):

Release **homeNavigationController** which not released and check if you are missing somewhere else.

Comment: Probably favouritesNavigationController, aboutUsViewController need to be released as well?